# Update variable in child function for use in parent function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a variable that is defined in a parent function be modified in the child function and then returned back to the parent as an updated variable.

Code I have tried is below:

```js
let wuzi = 20;
console.log(wuzi); //20 as expected
testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi); //I need this to be 30

function testWuzi(wuzi) {
    wuzi = 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of good answers here that are broadly applicable. I'll add one that may work depending on your definition of "parent function" and "child function."

If your "child function" is nested inside of the "parent function" then the lexical scope of the outer function's variable can still be active in the inner function, as long as no other variable is declared using the same name in that inner function.

For example, if you simply remove the parameter from the function in the example you've provided, it works the way you want. The reference to `wuzi` in `testWuzi` becomes a *closure* that references the `wuzi` variable declared outside that function.

```js
let wuzi = 20;
console.log(wuzi); //20 as expected
testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi); //30

function testWuzi() {
    wuzi = 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for a function to modify the variable itself when a variable is passed into the function. The *value* of the variable is what's passed in, not the variable itself, and primitive types such as `20` are "immutable" values, so they cannot be modified.

So one option you have is to instead pass in an object, since objects can be modified.

```js
let wuzi = { value: 20 };
console.log(wuzi.value); //20 as expected
testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi.value); //I need this to be 30

function testWuzi(wuzi) {
    wuzi.value = 30;
}
```

Another option is to not attempt to have the function modify the value, but instead return an updated value. Some people would consider this to be the better approach since it avoids "side effects":

```js
let wuzi = 20;
console.log(wuzi); //20 as expected
wuzi = testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi); //I need this to be 30

function testWuzi(wuzi) {
    return wuzi + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because is passing by `value`,if you want to let it work as you expected,you need to change it pass by `reference`

One option is to store in `array`

```js
let wuzi = [20];
console.log(wuzi[0]); //20 as expected
testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi[0]); //I need this to be 30

function testWuzi(wuzi) {
    wuzi[0] = 30;
}
```

Another option is to store in `Object`

```js
let wuzi = {val:20};
console.log(wuzi.val); //20 as expected
testWuzi(wuzi);
console.log(wuzi.val); //I need this to be 30

function testWuzi(wuzi) {
    wuzi.val = 30;
}
```